# PHP (v 4.3 and 5.3) missing ; after continue works with print but not works with echo

Tags: php, echo, continue

I am testing code with **lower version v4.3 and v5.3** of PHP, this is bit of code with **continue after without semicolon**. Its works and give strange output.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    if ($i == 2)
        continue
    print "$i\n";
}
//Output: 2 its strange
```

But with `echo` throws error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    if ($i == 2)
        continue
    echo "$i\n";
}
//Output:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)
```

Comment: Wonder if it's something to do with `print` having a return...

Comment: I'm a little terrified at the thought of anyone running php v4 today! Please tell me this is just an exercise in curiosity and you're not actually planning to use these old php version for anything.

Comment: @Simba, yes, it just for practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `continue` statement accepts a parameter, so you can add more expressions after it:

```
continue <foo>;
```

`print` is an expression and can be used as part of other statements, so `continue print();` is valid syntax. This is also why `2` is being output, the single statement `continue print $i;` is being executed when `$i == 2`.

`echo` is a statement and can *not* be used as part of other expressions, `<anything> echo` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Up voted, but continue print() works with earlier version only not in new version 5.4 and later.

Comment: As @hanshenrik explained, dynamic values for `continue` have been deprecated and killed off, since it was a terrible idea. `continue 5` works, `continue func()` won't.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the continue statement accepts an optional integer (number of loops to continue), which defaults to 1 if none is given.

By not having a semicolon, PHP will take the next expression to be that integer. The language construct `print` returns an integer, so that's fine. However, `echo` is a also language construct, but it has no return value. So while the parser is looking for an integer, it bumps into a language construct without a return value, and it gets confused and raises an error.

The real solution is to put in that semicolon, because by not having one you are actually *potentially changing the behavior of the `continue`*.

(In this case you're not, because print *always* returns one, but in other cases it could actually introduce bugs into your code.)

Comment: Not quite correct. PHP being a dynamically typed language, it doesn't care about the return **type**. That's not what's producing the error. A type mismatch would show up at runtime, if at all, not at parse time. The correct answer is that `print` is an *expression* while `echo` is a *statement*. `print` can be used as part of other expressions, `echo` can't.

Comment: Yeah, agreed that your explanation is more correct. The technical reason for the error is statement vs expression. The practical issue here is that continue will try to grab the next expression to modify it's behavior if you don't put the semicolon, and you usually don't want that.

Comment: You said, **The language construct print returns an integer** then it works with later verison of 5.3

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure it's because, in earlier versions of php, you could do

```
function f(){return 2;}
for($i=0;$i<9;++$i){
for($ii=0;$ii<99;++$ii){
continue f();
}
}
```

and then it would continue on loop number returned by f() (in this case, the $i loop. if it returned 1, it would continue the $ii loop)
in modern versions of PHP, you can hardcode a  number, but you can't continue on a variable number anymore, it must be decided at compile time. and print() returns int. echo does not, which is why you get an error, the argument to continue must be an int.

Comment: ahh so it continue is parameterized statement it supports boolean in earlier version of php.. right?

Answer (score 0):

Reason : Output: 2

> because the entire continue print "$i\n"; is evaluated as a single
>   expression, and so print is called only when $i == 2 is true. (The
>   return value of print is passed to continue as the numeric argument.)

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: I already refer doc thats why I have asked here because I need actual reason not. in doc reason not mentioned